# If I run a script with nohup, which in turn calls another script, is the other script effected by nohup?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, nohup

So let's say I have a script called script1 who somewhere in the code calls script2:

```
...
./script2
...
```

And let's say I run script1 as such:

```
nohup ./script1
```

Will script2 be effected by the nohup?

Answer (score 3):

The `nohup` command *detaches* the command from the controlling terminal from which it is being run. Child processes inherit the environment from the parent process, thus are also detached.

The name of the command comes from "NO Hang-UP", refererring to [`SIGHUP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) signal. The signal is used to *notify* processes that the terminal is closed, and no more input/output is possible. The signal is sent only to the processes which are attached to the terminal (read from and/or write to; e.g. interactive user input/output). What `nohup` tool does, is to simply redirect input/output of the given command away from the terminal, thus making sure it will not receive the `SIGHUP` when the terminal closes. On the Unix-like OSs, the child processes automatically inherit the I/O redirection from the parent process.